# Мгновенные сообщения: COMET, количество запросов

Tags: comet, php, javascript

Занимаюсь разработкой Бесед аля *Диалоги во ВКонтакте*.

Две колонки - слева все беседы, справа блок сообщений (переписки).

Так вот мне нужно обновлять беседы (когда есть новые сообщения, прочтенные и т.п.).

И в то же время мне нужно обновлять текущий чат.

Думаю сделать одним запросом, где он уже сам будет отдавать то, что нужно. То есть, если есть обновления диалогов - то возвращаем ответ с диалогами, если сообщения - то соответственно.

Суть в том, чтобы не делать два comet-запроса, а сделать один, который обрабатывает все.

Как лучше сделать?

Comment: Идете в верном направлении. Лучше всего ответ клиенту отдавать в json обертке. Конкретизируйте, в чем именно непонятки возникли.

Comment: Понятно что в json. Проблема в том, чтобы не грузить сервер двумя активными comet-запросами. А сделать все в одном. То есть, одна "функция" на сервере обрабатывает два запроса (диалоги и текущий чат).

Comment: @exec ну да, создаете одно соединение, и пихаете все данные туда :) Как понять "одна "функция" на сервере обрабатывает два запроса"? Я думаю, что это должно работать так: На сервере происходит событие (сообщение в диалогах или чате), сервер отдает данные с определенной пометкой. По скольку поступление сообщений тоже занимает один запрос и вы не сможете отослать сообщение на тот-же сервер, на котором открыто соединение, по этому нужно второе соединение на другой домен.

Comment: @lampa, одна функция - разные аргументы. Диалоги или сообщения, результат меняется. - это не важно. я это сказал чтоб понятно было :D

Суть в том, сделать так чтобы не висело два запроса у юзера.

Comment: Не понимаю вас, или вы меня :D

    <?php
    
    $firstReq = query('диалоги');
    $secondReq = query('сообщения');
    
    $json_en = json_encode(
     array('диалоги'=>$firstReq, 'сообщения'=>$secondReq)
    );
    ?>
    
    
    $.comet({
     message: function(data) {
      if(data.диалоги != null) {
       //... 
      }
      
      if(data.сообщения != null) {
       //... 
      }
     } 
    });

Comment: Я Вам разве давал свой код? :) Так бывает, совпало.

Comment: @exec просто это самое простое и хорошее решение :)

Comment: @exec, еще можете использовать websockets, если таковых поддерживает браузер: http://habrahabr.ru/post/79038/

Comment: @Dobby007, уже реализовал - пользователи общаются, пока все нормально, правда есть некоторые ошибки в реализации.

Comment: `COMET` по своей природе похож на костыли из прошлого c различными паттернами реализации. 2016 год, `websocket` используйте. P.S Могу вам предложить воспользоваться вебсокетами на gif расширении, даже в IE6 будет работать https://github.com/videlalvaro/gifsockets :)